# Sorting array where many of the keys are identical - time complexity analysis

Tags: time-complexity

The question goes like this:

> Given an array of n elements where [image] elements are same. Worst case time complexity of sorting the array (with RAM model assumptions) will be:
>
> 1. [image]
> 2. [image]
> 3. [image]
> 4. [image]
> 5. [image]
> 6. [image]

So, I thought to use selection algorithm in order to find the element whose size is the [image], call it P. This should take O(n). Next, I take any element which doesn't equal this element and put it in another array. In total I will have k=n-n^(2001/2002) elements. Sorting this array will cost O(klog(k)) which equals O(nlogn). Finally, I will find the max element which is smaller than P and the min element which is bigger than P and I can sort the array.

All of it takes O(nlogn).

Note: if [image], then we can reduce the time to O(n).

I have two question: is my analysis correct? Is there any way to reduce time complexity? Also, what is the RAM model assumptions?

Thanks!

Comment: What sorting algorithm are you supposed to use?

Comment: @user2357112, any kind of sorting algorithm. I need to find an implementation of sorting the array at best time complexity. As I stated, I can do it in O(nlogn). The question is if I can find something which is better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is wrong - there is no guarantee that the `n^(2001/2002)`th-smallest element is actually one of the duplicates.

`n^(2001/2002)` duplicates simply don't constitute enough of the input to make things easier, at least in theory. Sorting the input is still at least as hard as sorting the `n - n^(2001/2002) = O(n)` other elements, and under standard comparison sort assumptions in the RAM model, that takes at least `O(n*log(n))` worst-case time.

(For practical input sizes, `n^(2001/2002)` duplicates would be at least 98% of the input, so isolating the duplicates and sorting the rest would be both easy and highly efficient. This is one of those cases where the asymptotic analysis doesn't capture the behavior we care about in practice.)

Comment: Thank you for a great answer!